# how to skip rendering views in a json format request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

There are tons of data in a JSON request.

However, the bottleneck is in the `Views`.

`Views: 32459.3ms`

How to skip rendering the views and response the query data to user ? Thanks

```
Write page /Users/public/index.json (35.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 40488ms (Views: 32459.3ms | ActiveRecord: 336.8ms)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you can use > render json: {respones: resp.to_json}